# What is wrong with my contact from?

Tags: php, html, contacts, contact-form

On my website there is a contact form, for some reason after filling out the form, I won't get an email.
Below is the code for the form followed by the code for the sendmail.php code page.  
 *For privacy I removed my email and replaced it with email@domain.com

 
Anyone know what could be wrong? 
Thanks in advance, 
Peter

contact.html Page Snip --

```
    <div class="contact-us container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="contact-form span7">
                <p>Please fill out the form below and we'll get back to you as soon as we can! </p>
                <form method="post" action="assets/sendmail.php">
                    <label for="name" class="nameLabel">Name</label>
                      <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name...">
                    <label for="email" class="emailLabel">Email</label>
                      <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email...">
                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                      <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your subject...">
                    <label for="message" class="messageLabel">Message</label>
                      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
                    <button type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Sendmail.php --

```
// Email address verification
function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {

// Enter the email where you want to receive the message
$emailTo = 'email@doamin.com';

$clientName = trim($_POST['name']);
$clientEmail = trim($_POST['email']);
$subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);

$array = array();
$array['nameMessage'] = '';
$array['emailMessage'] = '';
$array['messageMessage'] = '';

if($clientName == '') {
    $array['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your name.';
}
if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
    $array['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
}
if($message == '') {
    $array['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
}
if($clientName != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $message != '') {
    // Send email
$headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail;
mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

echo json_encode($array);

}

?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to troubleshoot it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- on the sendmail.php page?

Comment: Sure, but it's okay to put it on all PHP pages.

Comment: the contact page is a .html page

Comment: have you checked whether you are getting all the post values or not?

Comment: Use PHP's own function `filter_var` instead of your `isEmail` to validate the email!

Comment: There could be many things wrong. For example, have you checked if `mail()` actually works in your configuration? I'm afraid Stack Overflow is not a debugging forum. You should first run a few tests and narrow down your problem to a specific topic you wish to ask about.

Comment: Use **correct** headers on your mail function! `Name: Value\r\n` for **each propertie** - Add an `\r\n` at your last propertie!

Comment: Put it inside all pages using PHP code. @Peter and use `var_dump()` to track variables.

Comment: Your code is based on `if($_POST)` conditional statement and since you're using `<button type="submit">Send</button>` that is not a POST variable element. 
Try changing it to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">` then try that. If it doesn't work, try changing `if($_POST)` to `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` while using my suggestion for the new submit button. @Peter I take it that you do have the `<form>...</form>` tags, right? It's not in your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `['submit']` is irrelevant, you can check a POST-Request only with `isset($_POST)` ;)

Comment: It's better practice. Once the page loads without using the submit button, it will assume POST is already set by another method. @AdrianPreuss

Comment: Sure, but the Questioneer saves with informations ;) We assume that this is the only form is what he owns.

Comment: @Peter There's nothing wrong with your code, I tested it. There are a few possible reasons. One is check your spam, another is to replace button with input type; some browsers don't execute it and mostly the older ones if that's what you're using. Another possible scenario is that you're running this from your own computer and PHP / mail is probably misconfigured. The list goes on.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Read my comment above for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `if($_POST)` to `if( ! empty($_POST))`. Also try `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of the page to make sure you're getting the variables through properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my working contact form in php i use following verification:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))
{
   // your send mail code
}
```

BTW if you call directly:

```
mail("youremail@domain" , " your subject" , " mail body" , "From: example@example.com" );
```

your mail arives in inbox? i ask because you may not have acces to sendmail function from php.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using**

Your'e using **PHP** - Why you dont use functions that provides by PHP?
`isEmail` is nonsense, use `filter_var` to validate E-Mails:

```
 if(filter_var($clientEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     // E-Mail is valid
 }
```

**2. POST Requests**

To check if the post-request is taken, use `isset` or `empty`:

```
 if(isset($_POST)) {
     // Send the mail...
 }
```

If you're using more than one form with an POST-Request on your side, be sure that you only handle the correct form. To prevent the problem, add an `name` attribute on your submit-button and check it:

```
 if(isset($_POST['yourFirstButton'])) {
     // Handle the first form
 }
```

And

```
 <input type="submit" name="yourFirstButton" value="Send" />
```

**3. Use correct mail headers**

Mail-Headers must be **valid**. A Propertie is `Name: Value\r\n` and **NOT** `Name: Value`.
You must add an `\r\n` at your **last entry**:

```
$headers = "From: " . $clientName . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail . "\r\n";
```

**4. Can your server send mails?**

If you dont receive mails, check your server configuration or ask your **server administrator**. PHP must be configured to sending mails. Install `sendmail` for example. Otherwise fill out the `SMPT` settings in your PHP-Configuration (`php.ini`) to send a mail over an mailserver.

**5. Using `mail`**

Why you use the `mail` function? Mostly you (the programmer) must deal with headers and other to send a **valid** mail - Otherwise, the mailserver decline/bounce the mail or the mail goes to your spam folder.

If you're using `mail`, check the **output:**

```
$test = mail(/* Your parameters */);
var_dump($test);
```

If it's returned `1` or `true`, PHP says that the mail was probably sent.

Use an PHP Mailer class like `PHPMailer` (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)